# suddenly flash notification in a function stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a login page which shows flash notifications on errors.

following are errors on which it shows flash notification:

1.when the user has not confirmed his/her email id.
2.when user enters wrong login credentials.

it was working fine few days ago but now it shows error

> undefined index password

my logic:

```
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request,[

                'loginEmail'=> 'required' ,
                'loginPassword' => 'required'

                ]);


        $remember = $request->input('remember_me');

        $user=User::where('email', $request['loginEmail'])->first();


        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['loginEmail'], 'password' => $request['loginPassword'],'confirmed'=>1],$remember))
        {




            //return redirect()->route('myplace');
            return redirect()->route('myplace',['username' => $user->username]) ;
        }
        if(Auth::attempt(['confirmed'=>0]))
        {
 \Session::flash('message','Please verify your email!');
        \Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-warning'); 
        return redirect()->back();
        }
        if(!Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['loginEmail'], 'password' => $request['loginPassword']]))
        {
        \Session::flash('message','Login credentials are wrong!');
        \Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-warning'); 
            return redirect()->back();
            }


    }
```

Comment: Check the full error message, it says what class and line causes the error.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin exact error:ErrorException in /home/aksoutco/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php line 116:
Undefined index: password

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if(Auth::attempt(['confirmed'=>0]))
```

You can't use `attempt()` without passing password. So try to use same code you use later in the code:

```
Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['loginEmail'], 'password' => $request['loginPassword']])
```

Comment: i tried: 

if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['loginEmail'], 'password' => $request['loginPassword'],'confirmed'=>0])) but what hapened is that i logged in  which should not happen as email is not confirmed

Comment: Since you've got user's email, you can get user by from DB by email `$user = User::where('email', $request['loginEmail'])->first();` and then check if it's confirmed or not. I don't see DB structure, but the code will look like this: `if ($user->confirmed == 1)`

Comment: can u provide me exact structure. here what i tried : http://pastebin.com/cKSVgYUK

Comment: You're using a lot of ifs and redundand data, code is not readable. You really need to rewrite the code.

Comment: 1st if is for wrong credentials ..2nd is for checking if confirmed is 1 ,if true then login.....last is for showing error of email confirmaton.